# Authenticated users changing personal details

Tags: security, edit

We have a website where users authenticate with a username/password and also have the option of switching on two factor authentication

One of the options they have in our application is to amend their home address which is then immediately updated on our back-office database

One client has asked for an extra later of security (their words, not mine) for when the user does this.

We've discussed sending a PIN to the mobile number or email we have recorded for the user, - I was wondering what others have implemented (if anything at all!)

Feels a little overkill to me as they are not changing bank details or any sort of payment instruction

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From a UX perspective - not a security perspective - you want the customer to feel comfortable with your site. Having them "feel" secure is important. The home address may, or may not, be valuable information worth protecting to you but safe keeping of data is valuable to lots of users.

Allowing users to opt-in to 2FA (two factor authentication) is a simple way for keeping security-conscious users feeling comfortable using your site.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, according to EU GDPR, address is **sensitive**. And @Mayo said to make them feel safe, that's true. *Guests are god.* The guest might be thinking about `Mr Hacker` ordering 1000 tons of french fries and sent them to their place, so they thought a confirm is needed.
Here's my solution:

1. Allow users to create address with labels like `home`, `office`, `school`, etc.
2. Only show the label when the address is needed(ie. when placing the order, the user selects the address labelled `home`)
3. On the profile page, show them the labels and give them a `show detail` button. After clicking the button, ask for 2FA credentials. If correct, show them the address alongside with a edit button (a pencil icon).
4. (Optional) Force them to set up 2FA when they need to do so to reduce SMS fees.

Godaddy/Github has implemented such thing:

- Log in with ease.
- Require password when performing some actions. (AKA `sudo mode` in Github)
- Require 2FA when doing super dangerous things.